# Unexpectedly uninitialised data in call to member function through lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, this

Consider the following short program. I am using `std::function` and a lambda to set a member function object (`initialise`) to a member function (`initialiser`) within the same class (`A`). `initialise()` is then being called in 4 places: 1. in the constructor of `A` from `main`, 2. directly from `main`, 3. in the constructor of `A` from the constructor of `B`, and 4. directly from the constructor of `B`.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <functional>
    #include <vector>

    class A {
    public:
        A(std::vector<int> const& sizes) : m_sizes(sizes) {
            set_initialiser();
            initialise();
        }
        A() = default;
        std::function<void()> initialise;
        void set_initialiser() { initialise = [this]() {return initialiser(); }; };
        // void set_initialiser() { initialise = std::bind(&A::initialiser, this); }; // the same occurs if I use bind instead of a lambda

    private:
        std::vector<int> m_sizes;
        void initialiser() {
            std::cout << "m_sizes size = " << m_sizes.size() << ", with contents:";
            for (auto & s : m_sizes)
                std::cout << " " << s;
            std::cout << std::endl;
        };
    };

    class B {
    public:
        B(std::vector<int> const& v) {
            a = A(v);
            a.initialise(); // here a.m_sizes and a.initialise.functor.this.m_sizes differ
        };
    private:
        A a;
    };

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        auto a = A({ 4,3,2,1 });
        a.initialise();
        auto b = B({ 4,3,2,1 });
        return 0;
    }
```

Compiling and running this code gives the following unexpected (for me at least) behaviour.

```
m_sizes size = 4, with contents: 4 3 2 1                                                                                
m_sizes size = 4, with contents: 4 3 2 1                                                                                            
m_sizes size = 4, with contents: 4 3 2 1                                                                                
m_sizes size = 0, with contents:
```

Could anyone elucidate as to why the last call to `initialise()` contains an uninitialised `m_sizes`? I suspect it must be something to do with different instances of `this` being used in the lambda, but I don't see why there should be any difference in calling it from `main` and calling it from another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = A(v);
```

This line creates a temporary object `A(v)` (I'll call it `t`), and copies its data into `a`. `t.initialise` contains a lambda which has captured `this` (that is, `&t`) by value. You then copy this lambda into `a.initialise`; note, however, that it still refers to `&t`.

Then, the full expression ends, `t` is destroyed (since it was a temporary), and the captured pointer inside `a.initialise` is now dangling. The next call of `a.initialise()` thus dereferences a dangling pointer, giving you Undefined Behaviour.

Note that the exact same problem (same Undefined Behaviour) happens in your `main` too, but its effect is different. What follows is a speculation on why, but bear in mind that *undefined behaviour is undefined* and anything can happen.

I suppose that inside `main`, copy elision occurs and the temporary `A({ 4,3,2,1 })` is constructed directly in the space of `a`, making its `this` identical to that of `a`, which makes the call to `initialise` still work.

Inside `B`'s constructor, copy elision is not possible (since you're doing assignment and not initialisation), so the temporary is indeed destroyed, leaving behind a correctly destroyed vector which happens to still be identical to an empty vector in your case (probably because it was moved from the temporary into `a`).

Once more: this is just speculation, and the code is simply wrong.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, thanks. If I insert an `a.set_initialiser();` directly before the `a.initialise();`, then this should update the `this` to point to the correct object, yes?

Comment: @BrettRyland Yes, certainly. You should probably consider implementing your own copy & move operations for your class and insert the call in them (if you need it in the first place).